# Why is this sum equal to 1?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm sorry for opening a new question for a triviality, but I couldn't find this result online.

The following holds:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {\dfrac{ {{K-1}\choose{j}} {{N-1-(K-1)}\choose{n-1-j}} } {{N-1}\choose{n-1} }}=1$$

It looks like an identity that I'm not aware of. I checked with easy numbers and all terms are different than 0. I only know of this identity $\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}=2^n$ which I don't think is any helpful.

Both $-1$ in the second binomial in the numerators have been added from a previous step, I guess in order to make it easier to understand why the sum is actually $1$.

I'd be glad if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: When in doubt you can do a proof by induction.  There's probably a combinatorial meaning and reason for it but I'd just muck it out arithmetically/inductively.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that by the [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients) Chu-Vandemonde Identity

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{k-1}j\binom{N-k}{n-1-j}= \binom{N-1}{n-1}$$

...and we're done